# Cannot launch pgadmin4

Tags: pgadmin-4

I have just installed pgadmin4-desktop on Fedora36. Can anyone provide some suggestions?

It was working fine a couple of days ago but now I cannot launch it via Gnome or the command line.

```
$ pwd
/usr/pgadmin4/bin 
$ ./pgadmin4
[0623/155920.067580:ERROR:zip_reader.cc(153)] Cannot open ZIP from file handle 3
[0623/155920.067718:ERROR:zip.cc(202)] Cannot open ZIP from file handle 3 Opening in existing browser session. 
$
```

Installed details from "yum list installed" are:

```
pgadmin4-desktop.x86_64                              6.10-1.fc35                         @pgAdmin4              
pgadmin4-fedora-repo.noarch                          2-1                                 @System                
pgadmin4-server.x86_64                               6.10-1.fc35                         @pgAdmin4
```

Finally, I found someone else with the same issue on Ubuntu but there is no answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1414609/run-pgadmin-4-on-ubuntu-22-04

Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn't a DBA question. It belongs on superuser.com

Comment: Sure. Sorry. I did look at meta exchange to try and find the right place.

Comment: In case anyone else comes to the wrong forum but is interested in the resolution, here is how I solved it. https://superuser.com/questions/1728081/cannot-launch-postgresqls-pgadmin4-on-fedora36?noredirect=1#comment2673002_1728081